# I want to increase the resolution of my webcam in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv

Is there a way to increase the webcam resolution of my webcam in OpenCV Python. The default value is 640x480 but, I want it to be 1365x730. Here's my code:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(1):
    _, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: …does your webcam physically support that resolution? Software can't improve hardware. Also, please read [ask]. Your question isn't very clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280)
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720)
while(1):
    _, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: @MelAbgrall I tried that one but it only changes the size. Not the resolution.

Comment: @sharifa as Chris stated you need to check the resolution of your webcam. If you are running ubuntu and have v4l2 installed you can check everything with `v4l2-ctl --all`